# How to create custom font icons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome, webfonts

I want to add some custom font icons in my project. Because default icons in bootstrap is not enough. How to create custom font icons in bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fontcustom](http://fontcustom.com/) will help to generate custom icon webfonts from the comfort of the command line. Your icons should be in svg format.

- Installation:

  `sudo apt-get install fontforge wget
  http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/woff-code-latest.zip
  unzip woff-code-latest.zip -d sfnt2woff
  cd sfnt2woff
  make sudo mv sfnt2woff /usr/local/bin/
  gem install fontcustom`
- Steps to create font icons

  1. copy all the svg file in a single directory.
  2. execute `fontcustom config /path/to/vectors` .  It will Generate .yml file
  3. execute `fontcustom compile /path/to/vectors`. It Generate `app` directory with font and stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

### How to create custom font icons (and glyph names) from existing fonts

- Obtain the font you want to use from free sources, such as http://fontello.com/ ; or create/modify a font using a library such as https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/ - which you can also use to rename your font, add your own copyright, or re-generate the font id.
- You can either read the glyph-names and glyph-codes from the font itself by using a library such as: https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib and (optionally) save the information in JSON or CSS   **-OR-**   you can edit the accompanying CSS file you got with your font, bulk replacing the font-family-name and font-class-names you want -in your favorite text editor.
- Use the appropriate `@font-face` sources as indicated, however, `woff` is a widely supported.
- Remember to maintain the correct glyph-codes (usually unicode) corresponding to the glyph-names you assign in the CSS -which you can either generate once and save as a CSS file, -or generate on-the-fly with JavaScript and inject into the DOM `<head>` as `<style>`.

You can edit (or create) your CSS to recognize your glyph classes in a way that you do not need to use duplicate words such as `icon icon-smile` like this:

#### Icon-fonts CSS for using shorter class-names

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Some_Font';
    src: url('fnt/Some_Font.woff?v=0.1.0') format('woff');
}

[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before
{
    font-family: "Some_Font";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    speak: none;

    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-smile:before{content:'\eAA0';}
```

Now you can simply use your custom glyphs without duplicating the font-name like this:

```
<i class="icon-smile"></i>
```

Use your own discretion when naming your fonts and classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try icomoon which lets you create our own custom font icons using plain svg files.

For a full explanation see https://impressto.net/creating-font-icons