# Replacing glyph icons with FontAwesome icons

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome, glyphicons

For collapse/expand icons curretnly I have this in my Razor code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
```

So it has the "+" and "-" icons that my JS uses to toggle between them.

Now I want to use Up and Down arrows, how can I use `FontAweosme` up and down arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
<span><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>
<span><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
```

Comment: Thanks will mark your's as answered but acutally I found that glyph icons have that icon too, so ended up using this: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>

Comment: Oh great. It will hopefully help someone else in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### To replace "Glyph Icons" with "FontAwesome"

Visit: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/ and follow instructions.

#### Icon-font replacement and custom font glyphs

If you're looking for in depth control over custom fonts and glyph-class-names, see these answers: [How to create custom font icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255773/how-to-create-custom-font-icons/36586576#36586576)

Comment: It may help someone out there.